# page reloading even function returning false

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button in html

```
<button class="widget-planner-submit" type="submit" value="Go" onclick="onRedirect('button');" >GO</button>
```

Even if javascript function returns false the page reloads on click of Go button.

Comment: onclick="return onRedirect('button');"

Comment: yes it worked.. but why it worked perfectly on link without "return" but not on button

Comment: submit already submits the form before even checking the return by the function, so it needs to be restricted by making it to wait for the return, i guess.. am not sure , its just my thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<button class="widget-planner-submit" type="submit" value="Go" onclick="return onRedirect('button');" >GO</button>
```